# How to add to array in doubly nested subdocument in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have defined following schemas, where the schema are doubly nested.

A topic can have multiple questions, and each questions can have multiple answers (like multiple choice answers). The answer can also have multiple code(s) attached to it.

```
const answersOptionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    label: String,
    codes: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Code',
      },
    ],
  }
)

const questionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    label: String ,
    options: [answerSchema],
  }
)

const topicSchema = new Schema(
  {
    label: String,
    questions: [questionSchema],
  }
)
```

Example document:

```
  {
      "_id": "TopicId1",
      "label": "topic",
      "questions": [
        {
          "_id": "QuestionId1",
          "label": "How are you feeling today?",
          "options": [
            {
              "_id": "OptionId1",
              "label": "I'm feeling good.",
              "codes": ["codeId1"]
            },
            {
              "_id": "OptionId2",
              "label": "I'm feeding okay.",
              "codes": ["codeId2", "CodeId3"]
            }
          ],
        },
      ]
    }
```

Now, I want to insert a code to given answer schema id. I have tried the following

```
 const result = await Topic.updateOne(
      { 'questions.options._id': 'OptionId1'},
      {
        $addToSet: {
          'questions.options.$.codes': 'CodeId4',
        },
      }
    )
```

I am getting following error

```
MongoError: Cannot create field 'options' in element
```

I think the problem is that there are two levels of nested arrays and the $ operator can only serve one index. Is there any other way that I can achieve what i want to?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like following an it worked

```
const topic = await Topic.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'questions.options._id': 'OptionId1' },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      'questions.$[].options.$[option].codes': 'CodeId4',
    },
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [{ 'option._id': 'OptionId1' }],
    new: true,
  },
)
```